# Why does eclipse cannot find the source of service module in multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a multi-module maven project and when I open the implementation of my service that is located in service module it says Source not found but I can open the class using ctrl + shift + R.

Comment: Strange ! okay try one thing, build your project from command line, see if your compiler finds your service class. Coz what i figure out is, the jar is included in the class path (in eclipse env). try  it once.

Comment: My (service-core.jar) jar is included in build path of Maven dependencies. How do I exclude it when importing in eclipse. Because in my other maven project the jar of other module is not included in maven dependencies build path.

Comment: there is no need to add jar manually to build path, maven dependencies are automatically put onto the build path. My concern was, may be your project has the jar added to your project build path(manually, not by maven) that is why i asked you to build your project from command line.